# Spring hibernate exception creating EntityManagerFactory - NegativeArraySizeException: -947658752

Tags: spring-boot, sqlite, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have a spring boot application that serves map tiles from an SQLite database stored within the resources directory. This application runs perfectly fine within an IDE, and have never had an issue until I was attempting to run the compiled jar with the java -jar command. The database is being built into the JAR, but I don't understand how that could be an issue at all. When I run the compiled jar I get the following exception:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource
     [com/app/application/configuration/MapDataSourceConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -947658752




org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/app/application/configuration/MapDataSourceConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -947658752
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.app.map.MapApplicationKt.main(MapApplication.kt:12)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)

Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -947658752
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ArchiveHelper.getBytesFromInputStream(ArchiveHelper.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.ArchiveHelper.getBytesFromInputStreamSafely(ArchiveHelper.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.spi.AbstractArchiveDescriptor.buildByteBasedInputStreamAccess(AbstractArchiveDescriptor.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.internal.JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.visitArchive(JarFileBasedArchiveDescriptor.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.boot.archive.scan.spi.AbstractScannerImpl.scan(AbstractScannerImpl.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.ScanningCoordinator.coordinateScan(ScanningCoordinator.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.prepare(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:182)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:52)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
```

Application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
  datasource:
    map:
      url: jdbc:sqlite:backend/src/main/resources/db/mbtile/map.mbtiles
      driver-class-name: org.sqlite.JDBC
      configuration:
        maximum-pool-size: 1
```

MapDataSourceConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackageClasses = [Tile::class],
    basePackages = ["com.app.domain.repository.map"],
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "mapEntityManagerFactory"
)
class MapDataSourceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.map")
    fun mapDataSourceProperties(): DataSourceProperties = DataSourceProperties()

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.map.configuration")
    fun mapDataSource(properties: DataSourceProperties): HikariDataSource =
        properties.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(HikariDataSource::class.java).build()

    @Bean
    fun mapEntityManagerFactory(): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean = (LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean()).apply {
        dataSource = mapDataSource(mapDataSourceProperties())
        setPackagesToScan("com.app.domain.model.map")
        jpaVendorAdapter = HibernateJpaVendorAdapter()
    }
}
```

Tile.kt:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(TileCompositeKey::class)
@Table(name = "tiles")
data class Tile(
    @Id @Column(name = "zoom_level") val zoomLevel: Int = 0,
    @Id @Column(name = "tile_column") val tileColumn: Int? = 0,
    @Id @Column(name = "tile_row") val tileRow: Int? = 0,
    @Column(name = "tile_data") val tileData: ByteArray? = null,
)

private class TileCompositeKey(
    private val zoomLevel: Int? = 0,
    private val tileColumn: Int? = 0,
    private val tileRow: Int? = 0,
) : Serializable
```

Build.gradle.kts:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.32.3.2")
    implementation("com.github.gwenn:sqlite-dialect:0.1.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.14.1")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.14.1")
}
```

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: what is the size of your jar file?

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov The file is 3.2GB, to your point it does work with a 400MB db. Is there a way to increase the limit it can use under the resource folder?